# If function to write to either sheet1 or both sheet1 and sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write an if function into a save button on a user-form so that if the data entered into the user-form is already on sheet 2 then it only gets written to sheet 1. But if it does not exist on sheet 2 then the data from the user-form gets written to both sheet 1 and sheet 2. This is because I want the data on sheet 2 to act like a sort of database and obviously do not want duplicates. I've made the write procedures into two separate modules (I figured this would make it easier to differentiate). Here is my code (Be gentle I'm still learning)

```
Sub writetosheet1()
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
i = i + 1
Wend

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt1.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt2.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt3.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("d" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt4.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("e" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt5.Value
End Sub

Sub writetosheet2()

Dim i As Integer
i = 1
While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
i = i + 1
Wend


ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt1.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt2.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("c" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt4.Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("d" & i).Value = UserForm1.txt5.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CMDSAVE_Click()
Dim id As Long
id = txt1.Value
If id <> Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a:a").Value Then
Call writetosheet1
Call writetosheet2
Else
Call writetosheet1

End If
End Sub
```

Any help on this would be fantastic! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can not compare one single value with whole range like this:

```
If id <> Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a:a").Value Then
```

You need to go trough all cells in that range separately.

```
If Application.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A:A"), id) > 0 then
 'write only to sheet1
else
 'write to both sheets
end if
```

Comment: I get a runtime 13 error type mismatch on this line:                                      id = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a:a").Value

Comment: Yes exactly, as I wrote above,: Replace your "If" statement with mine.